# Get nav to show and hide with querySelector and display none/block?

Tags: javascript, display, queryselector

Im trying to make a navbar that shows and hides when you press a button. I get it to show but not hide. If anyone know how i can add a litte fade animation when its shows please let me know.

I have used js and querySelector to get it to shoew.

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button");

let press = document.querySelector('nav').style.display = 'none';
press = true;

button.onclick = () => {

    if(press == true){
        document.querySelector('nav').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else  if(press == false){
        document.querySelectorAll('nav').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

This makes the nav to show but it wont hide again.

Comment: I think it's because the value `press` never changes. You could put the line `let press = ...` inside the onClick function to make your example work.

If you are using CSS/SCSS, I'd suggest to use a class for this and just add/remove the class on the clicks, depending on the class being present or not.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `press` value for the next click.

```
    if(press == true){
        document.querySelector('nav').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.querySelectorAll('nav').style.display = 'none';
    }
    press = !press;
```